# How to use DispatcherListener in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, initialization, startup, dispatcher

There is a interface `DispatcherListener` in Struts2. The docs says

> "A interface to tag those that want to execute code on the `init` and
>   `destroy` of a `Dispatcher`."

But how to use this interface. If I create a class that implements this interface, how should I configure it to Struts2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a `Dispatcher` is instantiated, it could send to the listener notification when it's initialized or destroyed. The reference and code samples are from [here](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/DispatcherListener.html).

The simple usage is to instantiate a bean by the container via `bean` tag and add themselves in the `init` method and remove themselves when destroyed like it did by the [`ClasspathConfigurationProvider`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-plugins/struts2-convention-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/convention/ClasspathConfigurationProvider.html).

The code is raw just for to show you the idea

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<bean type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.PackageProvider" name="myBean" class="jspbean.struts.MyBean" />
```

**`MyBean.java`:**

```
public class MyBean implements ConfigurationProvider, DispatcherListener {
  public MyBean() {
    System.out.println("!!! MyBean !!!");
  }

  @Override
  public void dispatcherInitialized(Dispatcher du) {
    System.out.println("!!! dispatcherInitialized !!!");
  }

  @Override
  public void dispatcherDestroyed(Dispatcher du) {
    System.out.println("!!! dispatcherDestroyed !!!");
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("!!! destroy !!!");
    Dispatcher.removeDispatcherListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void init(Configuration configuration) throws ConfigurationException {
    System.out.println("!!! init !!!");
    Dispatcher.addDispatcherListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean needsReload() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void loadPackages() throws ConfigurationException {

  }

  @Override
  public void register(ContainerBuilder builder, LocatableProperties props) throws ConfigurationException {

  }
}
```

**The output:**

```
15:27:50  INFO (org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory:42) - ... initialized Struts-Spring integration successfully
!!! MyBean !!!
!!! init !!!
jul 18, 2013 3:27:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
!!! dispatcherInitialized !!!
[2013-07-18 06:28:11,102] Artifact jspbean:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
!!! dispatcherDestroyed !!!
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So the only way to use DispatcherListener is to make my own class that extends StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter and add the code samples to my subclass, and then configure it at the web.xml instead of StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.

Comment: No, shouldn't do that, you could do it with any bean managed by the container.

Comment: You mean I should create my own bean with the code samples and set it managed by the container?

Comment: If you create it via the config then it's already managed, in the code examples the bean implements `ConfigurationProvider` that might not necessary in this case.

Comment: I am sorry but I am confused how to use ClasspathConfigurationProvider. Can I use like this:         <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>configProviders</param-name>
         <param-value>org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathConfigurationProvider</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>                                                         But if I use like this, It will throw "java.lang.InstantiationException: "

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring then you can create bean of your listener and in constructor add it to `dispatcherListeners` list.

```
public YourDispatcherListener () {
  Dispatcher.addDispatcherListener(this);
}
```

Another solution is to create `ServletContextListener` which creates your dispatcher listener and adds it to list.