# Logs not printing after migrating from log4j-1.2.17 to Log4j2 2.17.1

Tags: java, environment-variables, struts2, log4j2

I am trying to migrate from `log4j-1.2.17` to `log4j-api-2.17.1` but after all the changes, the logs are not getting printed. I am using 'Option 2' as suggested by the https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html .

I have added `lo4j-api-2.17.1.jar` and `log4j-core-2.17.1.jar` in my libs folder and properly configured `log4j2.xml` in the `src/resources/...` folder.

There are no build errors nor any errors or warnings in my console when I run my `Weblogic 12c` server. It is a `jdk 1.6` and `struts 2` java web application.

The logs print fine when I use below VM args:

```
-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=%LOG_PATH% -Dlogpath=%LOGS%
set LOG_PATH=C:\bea\user_projects\domains\app_domain\conf\log4j2.xml
set LOGS=C:\bea\user_projects\domains\app_domain\logs
```

But this method is not acceptable for Prod env due to business requirements. Is there any alternative to perform the tasks of VM args through java code without using the VM args?

Answer (score 1):

The alternative way is to use `System` properties. Then you programmatically add properties:

```
System.setProperty("log4j2.configurationFile", "/path/to/log4j2.xml");
```

You can add this code to the dispatcher listener. See [how the dispatcher listener should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17700813/573032).

**Referencies:**

- The [System Properties tutorial](https://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).
- The javadoc for [`System.setProperty(String key, String value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).